# In SQL, select the unique elements of a column whose count exceeds a given number

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table "Orders" like below:

[image]

I've entered this into SQLfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9d7a/6) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
    (`Number` int, `order_date` varchar(10), `cust_id` int, `salesperson_id` int, `Amount` int)
;

INSERT INTO Orders
    (`Number`, `order_date`, `cust_id`, `salesperson_id`, `Amount`)
VALUES
    (10, '8/2/96', 4, 2, 540),
    (20, '1/30/99', 4, 8, 1800),
    (30, '7/14/95', 9, 1, 460),
    (40, '1/29/98', 7, 2, 2400),
    (50, '2/3/98', 6, 7, 600),
    (60, '3/2/98', 6, 7, 720),
    (70, '5/6/98', 9, 7, 150)
;
```

I would like to select the elements of `salesperson_id` which occur more than once. Till now I've done

```
SELECT
  salesperson_id
FROM
  Orders
GROUP by salesperson_id
```

but this leads to a selection of all unique elements of `salesperson_id` - that is, `1`, `2`, `7`, and `8` - and not just the ones that occur more than once, i.e., `2` and `7`. Is there any way I can do `GROUP by` specifying a minimum count number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT salesperson_id, count(salesperson_id) as c
FROM Orders 
GROUP by salesperson_id 
HAVING c>1
```

or even shorter

```
SELECT salesperson_id FROM Orders GROUP by salesperson_id HAVING count(salesperson_id)>1
```